# Hiding an element on pageLoad() with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

If I hide some elements on page_load using jquery, the elements flicker for a split second when the page posts and then disappear:

```
  function pageLoad() {

        $('#panelOne').hide();
        $('#panelTwo').hide();
```

Is there a way to prevent the flickering?

I don't want to set the elements css to visibility: hidden, because then calling the jquery .show() method later on doesn't seem to show the element.

Comment: I usually just set display: none, but I would love to see a better solution if there is one.

Comment: Setting the css to display: none; is the best option. That will work with .show(); later. peace...

Comment: I've tried display:none; in CSS myself, but how do you get it to work without javascript to toggle the display if a user has disabled JS?

Comment: if they disable javascript you'll need to do it serverside.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Setting `visibility: hidden` doesn't work, but `display: none` does. [See jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/FvktL/)

You could do this on the DOMReady event, but it would be cleaner to do it in CSS.

Comment: hide()ing does set display to none anyway, so this shouldn't make any difference (except that hide() will avoid some edge case bugs by storing the original value of display)

Comment: I believe jQuery's hide method actually sets `display: none` for you.

Comment: Well yes.  But it's cleaner and almost certainly faster to do this in CSS.

Comment: The problem with the CSS approach is that you're then requiring javascript to show the content. Presumably, the whole reason it's delivered is for it to be shown at some point; those without javascript then miss out on the content.

Comment: @Bobby Not necessarily true.  The links that are being used to show the content might gracefully degrade to a page where the content is shown by default. Or perhaps the content is a by-the-way note, useful but not necessary. The correct approach depends on the circumstances.  I struggle to see that this merited a downvote.

Comment: Good points - and you're right about the downvote. I still think the approach of setting the CSS via javascript is slightly better but maybe that downvote was a little harsh; I'll undo if you make a trivial edit to your question (I cannot undo unless you do that, unfortunately)

Comment: @Bobby Done. You have a point too!  This is the typical SO issue of psychic debugging ;-)

Answer (score 4):

`$.show()` doesn't work on elements set to `visibility: hidden`. You need to use `display: none`. This will work out better for you than using jQuery to hide on DOM ready, and will absolutely guarantee you won't see flickering.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely use document ready as opposed to page load:

```
$(function() {
    $('#panelOne, #panelTwo')
        .hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than hide on pageload, hide it on domready like so:

```
$(function() { ........ });
```

Replace the ...... with your 2 lines of hiding.

Domready runs when the dom-tree has been built, and much earlier than pageLoad. Pageload waits for images and stuff to run. (asuming that you have pageLoad as following: `<html onload="pageLoad();">`).

Comment: Actually I still see flickering when doing this. Is that the same as document.ready()?

Comment: Yes, $(function) is a shorthand to document.ready. If you still see a flicker you need to consider hiding the element in code (html/css), and then showing it again in js when you want to.

Comment: @Sean: do you have an example URL? I'm struggling to understand the cause of the flicker.